# Making Button "release" on mouseleave OR mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple button created with HTML  tags which visually presses down and sends a user to a certain page when clicked.  I can get it to work when it is clicked normally, but I would like the button to "release" (return to original state) when the user un-clicks the mouse OR moves the mouse off the button.  I've looked at other suggestions out there, but haven't found one that works the way I want it to.  Below is the code I'm currently using (I know that in the current JQuery code the 'mouseup' function doesn't fire when the user move off the ; I just haven't found a suitable replacement so I reverted back to what worked initially).  I'm open to using something other than JQuery; that just seemed best at first.

HTML:

```
<div class="letter_buttons" onclick="window.location='index.php'">Active</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .letter_buttons {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 140px;
        background-color: #b2b2b2;
        border: 3px solid #2D2D2D;
        color: #2D2D2D;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.letter_buttons').mousedown(function() {
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px #888');
        $(this).animate({left: '+=1px'}, 0);
        $(this).animate({top: '+=1px'}, 0);
    });
    $('.letter_buttons').mouseup(function() {
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '2px 2px 2px #888');
        $(this).animate({left: '-=1px'}, 0);
        $(this).animate({top: '-=1px'}, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've never heard of "un-clicking" before :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason to use javascript for this. This could all be done with a few CSS rules. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPHDH/))

HTML:

```
<a class="letter_buttons" href="#">Active</a>
```

CSS:

```
.letter_buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    border: 3px solid #2D2D2D;
    color: #2D2D2D;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.letter_buttons:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #888;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: when I change my button from <div> to <a>, I need to click a second time, off the button, for it to reset (your jsfiddle seems to do the same thing).  Is there a way to make it reset as soon as you release the mouse-button (un-click, as you might call it)?

Comment: That is weird. It definitely doesn't do that for me (and it should not). I can press the mouse button inside the `<a>`, move outside and release it, and the `<a>` goes back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using CSS3 since you are applying a box-shadow.

For that reason, I would do away with using jQuery for animation and use CSS3.  It'll be easier to maintain.

```
$('.letter_buttons').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

CSS - add this to your .letter_buttons class

```
div.letter_buttons {
    /* CSS3 transitions */

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Add this:

```
div.letter_buttons.active {
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888;
}
```

Comment: Why use javascript at all, instead of just using the :active pseudo-class which is made for this purpose?

Comment: good thought.  it doesn't solve the problem of a user moving their mouse off the <div> before the 'mouseup' action, but it does make the JQuery cleaner.